# VSCode Remote Server for React Development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is it possible to configure the VSCode Remote Server to expose ports other that SSH (22) back to the client? or perhaps another way to view the files from the server to a specific IP?

I am thinking of this in the context of React development.

I understand the one use case is to get more compute for tasks that simply would otherwise take a long time to run on your local machine; however I love the idea of offloading some of the longer running processes to a virtual machine in the cloud. I often want to run all of my code quality checks at the same time such as:

- linting
- unit tests
- integration tests
- coverage checks
- debugger
- server
- static analysis

However I've found this can bog down performance on my laptop to the point where it can slow down development so I don't really feel like that's very helpful right now. (This is on a Macbook Pro 2015 with 8GB of memory and a 2.7GHz i5 processor.)

If it's not possible to have any other connection between the server and client other than SSH which is my current understanding of how VSCode Remote works;  is there a way to expose what normally would be on localhost:3000 on the server to the client?  Better yet could that also expose a port (9222) that would support debugging in Chrome? Perhaps another approach would to still run the development server locally and `rsync` the files down from the server?

Has anyone tried to do anything like this before? Is this something that is possible? Also if anyone has any suggestions for running all those long running process locally in a more efficient way that doesn't cause the editor to lock up or the hot-reloading to be very slow I'd love to hear how I might be able to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [forward ports from the remote machine to your local machine](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_forwarding-a-port-creating-ssh-tunnel).

Once connected to the ssh workspace, simply run the `Remote-SSH: Forward Port from Active Host...` command to setup a port forwarding. See [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_forwarding-a-port-creating-ssh-tunnel) for more details and configuration options. I believe that port forwarding goes over an ssh connection internally but it seems like it address what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes that should cover most of my use case.  I'll look into that and post my results back here.  Thanks!